# Crystal Reports: This array must be subscripted

Tags: crystal-reports

**Code:**

```
NumberVar i;
StringVar Array aUsers; 

for i:= 1 to Ubound({?SYS_USER}) do 
(
        Redim Preserve aUsers[i];
        aUsers[i] := totext({?SYS_USER},0)[i];
);

Join (aUsers,", ");
```

Using Crystal Reports v11,

I am trying to display the paramters on the Report header, but I am getting an error:

> "This array must be subscripted"

My parameter, `SYS_USER` is dynamic and pulls through numeric and dynamic values, these values must be converted into a string to display the data I'm filtering for.

What is missing from my function causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change like this:

```
NumberVar i;
StringVar Array aUsers; 

for i:= 1 to Ubound({?SYS_USER}) do 
(
        Redim Preserve aUsers[i];
        aUsers[i] := totext({?SYS_USER}[i],0);
);

Join (aUsers,", ");
```